# Is there a possibility to get source code of ELF file using debug_info?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have a file with type: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), with debug_info, not stripped. Is there a way to get source code of this file? How can I use debug_info?

Comment: If you are asking whether the actual source code that went into producing the ELF (and binary) is somehow embedded in the ELF, then I believe the answer is no. There are probably tools out there that will allow you to reconstruct it to a certain extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a debugger or decompiler. The usual suspects for these applications are the linux programs `file` for file info, `gdb` for debugging, and recently with its open-sourcing of the NSA program `ghidra`; that is, if you trust a software produced by the NSA. `Ghidra` should be able to decompile your `ELF` to pseudo C, or at the very least machine code.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use `gdb` and `ghidra`. I need to get as many information about the file as I can get.